# Why does free(arr) delete only the first two elements of an array?

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

I have a simple code:

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int elms = 5;
    int* a = (int*) calloc(elms, sizeof(int));

    *a = elms;
    for(int i = 1; i < elms; i++){
        *(a + i) = i;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < elms; i++){
        printf("%d ", *(a + i));
    }

    printf("\n");

    free(a);
    // create new array with size increased by one
    int* arr = (int*) realloc(a, (elms + 1) * sizeof(int));
    *(arr + elms) = 10;

    for(int i = 0; i < elms + 1; i++){
        printf("%d ", *(arr + i));
    }

    printf("\n");    

    return 0;
}
```

[run on rextester](https://rextester.com/SOU46249)

Here I get the output as:

```
5 1 2 3 4 
0 0 2 3 4 10
```

My question is that why did the call to `free()` delete only the first two elements of the array? Either it should have deleted only the first element, or all the elements, but why two elements?

If I comment the call to `free()`, I get the expected output:

```
5 1 2 3 4 
5 1 2 3 4 10
```

Note: There is no change in output if I reassign the value of `realloc` back to `a`, as expected.

Comment: Calling `realloc( a, ...);` after `free( a );` is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  In other words, your code is broken when it does that.

Comment: `free` does not delete anything. The block of memory is just returned to memory management and you are not allowed to access it any longer. You might wonder why it does not crash then, but that is the nature of undefined behaviour.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Oh, sorry! I didn't know it is undefined behavior. In class our prof told us to do this only, so when i came back home it didn't work.

Comment: I guess the prof told you, to call `free` when you don't need the memory any longer. That is after `realloc` and the additional accesses to the memory, where `free` is missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You invoke undefined behavior with:

```
free(a);
// create new array with size increased by one
int* arr = (int*) realloc(a, (elms + 1) * sizeof(int));
```

Per [**7.22.3.5 The realloc function**, paragraph 3 of the C Standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.5p3) (bolding mine):

> if ptr does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function, **or if the space has been deallocated by a call to the `free`** or `realloc` function, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Oh, so this is double UB then.

Comment: @GaurangTandon The first one is in my answer (using an indeterminate value). The second one is in this answer (calling `realloc` with a pointer to deallocated memory).

Answer (score 2):

Your code has undefined behavior. Specifically:

```
free(a);
... realloc(a, ...);
```

After `free(a)`, the value of `a` is indeterminate. Trying to do anything with it (such as passing it to a function) has undefined behavior.

Any result is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers:

You probably want this:

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  int elms = 5;
  int* a = (int*)calloc(elms, sizeof(int));

  *a = elms;
  for (int i = 1; i < elms; i++) {
    *(a + i) = i;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < elms; i++) {
    printf("%d ", *(a + i));
  }

  printf("\n");

  // << don't call free(a) here, once you've done that
  //    a is "gone" forever.

  // create new array with size increased by one
  // << we use the same variable a as before, using another
  //    variable arr as you did is useless and confusing
  a = (int*)realloc(a, (elms + 1) * sizeof(int));
  *(a + elms) = 10;

  for (int i = 0; i < elms + 1; i++) {
    printf("%d ", *(a + i));
  }

  free(a);  // << call free(a) here once you're done with a

  printf("\n");    
  return 0;
}
```

Have a look the comments starting with `<<`

Output:

```
5 1 2 3 4
5 1 2 3 4 10
```